# Memory game doesn't open all cards upon starting

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a memory game in C#. It has 10 pairs of cards, total 20. It's supposed to work like this: When pressing the Start button, the game shuffles randomly the cards and reveals all cards. After 3 seconds it flips them. Then, the player has to find all pairs.

I'm having a problem with shuffling. I wrote this code. It's being executed when I press the Start button:

```
foreach (String icon in icons) 
            {
                int x1 = r.Next(1, 21);
                int x2 = r.Next(1, 21);
                if (!num.Contains(x1)) 
                {
                    num.Add(x1);
                }
                else 
                {
                    do
                    {
                        x1 = r.Next(1, 21);
                    } while (!num.Contains(x1));
                    num.Add(x1);
                }
                if (!num.Contains(x2))
                {
                    num.Add(x2);
                }
                else
                {
                    do
                    {
                        x2 = r.Next(1, 21);
                    } while (!num.Contains(x2));
                    num.Add(x2);
                }
                switch (x1) 
                {
                    case 1:
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        pictureBox4.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        pictureBox5.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        pictureBox6.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        pictureBox7.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        pictureBox8.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        pictureBox9.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        pictureBox10.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        pictureBox11.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        pictureBox12.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        pictureBox13.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        pictureBox14.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        pictureBox15.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 16:
                        pictureBox16.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 17:
                        pictureBox17.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 18:
                        pictureBox18.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 19:
                        pictureBox19.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 20:
                        pictureBox20.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                }
                switch (x2)
                {
                    case 1:
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        pictureBox4.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        pictureBox5.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        pictureBox6.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        pictureBox7.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        pictureBox8.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        pictureBox9.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        pictureBox10.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        pictureBox11.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        pictureBox12.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        pictureBox13.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        pictureBox14.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        pictureBox15.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 16:
                        pictureBox16.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 17:
                        pictureBox17.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 18:
                        pictureBox18.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 19:
                        pictureBox19.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                    case 20:
                        pictureBox20.Image = Image.FromFile(icon);
                        break;
                }
```

There is also an auxiliary list "num" and a list "icons", which contains the names of the icons' files.

```
List<int> num = new List<int>();
List<String> icons = new List<String>() { "agelada.png", "elefantas.png", "gata.png", "gatopardos.png", "kamilopardali.png", "liontari.png", "lykos.png", "skylos.png", "tigris.png", "zebra.png" };
```

This code is supposed to work like this:

~It generates two random numbers, from 1 to 20 (the game has 20 cards), and stores them into x1 and x2 respectively.

~For each icon, member of the "icons" list: If x1 isn't found in the list num, it gets added in it. If x1 is found, a new number is being generated, until generating one that isn't in "num". Then it gets stored in "num". Same for x2. This process repeats for all the member of the list "icons".

~Then, depending of the randomly generated numbers, the icon gets inserted into the respective pictureBoxes, for example, if the numbers are 6 and 17, the picture is entered into pictureBox6 and pictureBox17.

The goal of this process is to make sure that all 10 pictures are displayed exactly twice, to make pairs.

However, I have a problem. When I click on Start, not all cards are flipped (The question mark is the "back side" of the cards). It looks like this:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji5Lt.png)

It's supposed to show animal pictures in all cards.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing about the problem, but a few tips about the code: 1) Keep the picturBox controls in an array or a list and access them by index. It will help a lot to make your code cleaner. 2) Load images once, and care about disposing them. Do not load them from file every time.

Comment: It would be much better if you refactor the code, and debug the problem and update the question with a shorter and cleaner code and some debug info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the recommendations around managing the PictureBox controls in arrays, I would recommend you change the line (not shown) where you create the Random object to something like this:

```
    Random r = new Random(10);
```

Setting the seed like this while you're debugging will let you predict the output, and as you step through code from one run to the next run, it's easier to follow what's happening.

That said, if you stepped through this code:

```
    do
    {
        x1 = r.Next(1, 21);
    } while (!num.Contains(x1));
    num.Add(x1);
```

If you stopped the code on adding the value to your array, you would have seen the value already exists in the array, which is the opposite of the intended action.  That means your loop is exiting at the wrong time.

In this case, it's because your check is the opposite logic of what it should be, you want to keep running through this loop while the value is in the array.  In other words, changing both loops to look like this:

```
    do
    {
        x1 = r.Next(1, 21);
    } while (num.Contains(x1));
    num.Add(x1);
```

You will end up filling up your array with 20 unique values.

Comment: It worked. But when I click Start for a second time, the app freezes. Any ideas?

Comment: Only you can really answer that question.  You should break into the debugger to see where it's spending its time.  I would guess it has something to do with the num array being full already, but really you should see what's causing the problem.

Comment: Apparently it indeed had to do with the num list being full. I added "num.Clear();" as the first command in the button's code and now there are no freezes anymore. Thanks!